# Datatables query url string: need regex to fix url parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable

I'm building on top of a sample that I found here:
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/13488/adding-parameters-to-a-url-to-pre-filter

Can someone explain what this regex does and how I can modify it to accept blank spaces? Currently, when you enter a space the browser encodes it as %20. How can I get the browser to interpret the space as a space and filter the correct string?

Example: "http://example.com/list/?search=bobby%20flay" should still insert the string "bobby flay" in the Datatables search field. It also inserts the encoded string as "bobby%20flay" and obviously finds no results. Any ideas? Thanks.

```js
$.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (!results)
        {
            return;
        }
        return results[1] || "";
    };
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "oSearch": {"sSearch": $.urlParam('search')}
      
      ...
      
      });
```

Comment: to explain the regex and what it is doing, `[\\?&]` looks for a starting point of `?`, `&`, or \ before a token you pass in, followed by `=`. the `([^&#]*)` is a capture of anything after the `=` matched in the first portion that grabs 0 to n characters until it finds a '&' or '#' (the caret `^` negates the set). i would make a second function that calls the first one and uses a regex to replace %20 with a space which should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with what you currently have, it looks like you can replace both functions with below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var arr = window.location.href.split('='),
        search = arr[arr.length-1].replace(/%20/g, " "); 
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "oSearch": {"sSearch": search}
          });
     });
```

1) Wait for document to load

2a) Get url using window.location.href

2b) Use split to create an array at each instance of '='

3a) Get the length of the array, and get the last object: arr.length-1

3b)Use regex to replace each instance of %20 with " "

4) Pass the new string to your existing table function

Comment: This is great!  Just one problem... if the url has no parameters it feeds the whole url into the search field. 
EXAMPLES:  1) with parameter search contains "john smith" http:www.mysite.com/faq?search=john smith   2) no parameter the search contains url "http:www.mysite.com/faq"

Comment: I found the solution.  I'm pasting it below to help others.  :)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ 
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("search") > -1) {
  var arr = window.location.href.split('='),
  search = arr[arr.length-1].replace(/%20/g, " ");
 }
 else {search = "";}
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            "oSearch": {"sSearch": search}
          });
     });`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work: **https://jsfiddle.net/pdo5k5ht/**

```
 var urlString = "http://example.com/list/?search=bobby%20flay",
arr = urlString.split('='),
finalString = arr[arr.length-1].replace(/%20/g, " ");
alert(finalString );
```

Comment: Hey @mark think you could break it down for me? What's happening in the current regex and how can we integrate your solution?

Comment: @kevllar see other answer